# integration help with area

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area of the region bounded by the curves of $y=2x^2-3x+5$ and $y=x+11$.
So far I have done this:

$2x^2-3x+5 = x+11$

$2x^2-4x-6=0$

$2(x^2-2x-3)=0$

$(x-3)(x+1)=0$

$X=3, X=-1$

What do I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your intersection points, now we must analyze which function is on top and which one is on the bottom.

Looking at a graph, you can see that $y = x+11$ is the function on top.

Therefore, the function is : $x+11 - 2x^2 + 3x - 5 = -2x^2 + 4x + 6$

The integral becomes:

$$A =\int_{-1}^{3} (-2x^2 + 4x + 6) dx$$

Can you solve it from here?

Comment: Would it be [-2(x^3/3)+x^4]

Comment: Almost. You got the first variable correct. The other two would be $2x^2 + 6x$.

Comment: so [-2(X^3/3)+2x^2+6x]?

Comment: is the answer 40/3?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To find the intersection points: $2x^2-3x+5 = x+11 \Rightarrow 2x^2 -4x -6=0\Rightarrow x= 1\pm 2$.

Now, imagine a fiber inside the region . This fiber (shown in pink) will go from the parabola to the line, so the area would be the area under the line minus the area under the parabola:

$$\int_{-1}^3[(x+11)-(2x^2-3x+5)]\,dx.$$

Comment: Is the answer 40/3

Comment: @Ben Nope. It's $64/3$${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Now I see where I messed up its (54/3)+(10/3)

Comment: @Ben 
$$\int_{-1}^3[(x+11)-(2x^2-3x+5)]\,dx = \int_{-1}^3[-2x^2+4x+6]\,dx = \left[-\frac{2}{3}x^3 +2x^2 +6x\right]^3_{-1}=-18+18+18-\left(\frac{2}{3}+2-6\right)=18+\frac{10}{3}=\frac{64}{3}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help

Comment: That's alright, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If $∫f(x)dx = F(x) + C$, then $∫_a^b f(x) dx = F(b) - F(a)$

You have found $f(x) = -2x^2 + 4x + 6$, do you remember how to find F(x) from there?

Comment: The linear function is on top. Your function $f(x)$ is incorrect.

Comment: How do you do the integration sign?

Comment: @VarunIyer *headdesk* On it

Comment: @Ben use option-b

Comment: Is the answer 40/3

Comment: or is the answer 44/3